# Want to create a bar after Action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to create a toolbar or bar after action bar.

In toolbar if i click on previous button the text will change to previous date and if i press next button it is will change to next date.

How I can create the bar after action bar.

Comment: What do you mean by "after"? Under? Over? Next to?

Comment: On top there will be a action bar under that i want to create another bar

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the new Toolbar view. It was added to the support lib along with Android 5 and what it does is allow you to add the ActionBar as a simple View. You can then add your below view with simple "`android_below="@id/toolbarId`".